# How to run a .bat as admin

Tags: batch-file

I got a script working to look if the PC is 32 or 64 bit and start the line as being one of these bits. But now for some of our PC's in the domain it wont start right, at some it will open UAC and you have to enter admin credentials. But for al the others it will just run right. I added .batch to a GPO so it will run on Logon but now i want to include the runas Admin part so it will always run.

I did find some of these lines with runas and then a Admin Username, but none will ask for the password.

Underneith ill add my script what works right now, but without the Runas part. Can some 1 help me?

```
@echo off
 if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="AMD64" GOTO AMD64
 if /i "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%"=="AMD64" GOTO AMD64
 if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="x86" GOTO x86
 GOTO ERR
 :AMD64
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\CentraStage" start \\addc01\netlogon\centrastage\AgentSetup_Unmanaged.exe
 GOTO EXEC
 :x86
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\CentraStage" start \\addc01\netlogon\centrastage\AgentSetup_Unmanaged.exe
 GOTO EXEC
 :EXEC
    rem do arch independent stuff
 GOTO END
 :ERR
 @echo Unsupported architecture "%processor_architecture%"!
 :end
```

Comment: Have you identified the reason why the script requires admin priviledges on some but now all systems? Maybe you can avoid this problem in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the script using GPO and `RunAs` have you considered using Task Scheduler, `SchTasks/?`, as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, `/ru "System"`, instead.

You could probably improve your code a little too…

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "CS=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\CentraStage"
If "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" If Not Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Set "CS=%ProgramFiles%\CentraStage") 
If Exist "%CS%\" Exit/B
Start \\addc01\netlogon\centrastage\AgentSetup_Unmanaged.exe
Rem rest of code here
```